# TextBox with ControlTemplate - problem with property Text

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, controltemplate

I have one big problem with passing value from a `ControlTemplate` to the control. `TextBox` has a `ControlTemplate`, how can I pass value from this template to the `TextBox` text?

Comment: I've solved my problem. What I have to do is to use TwoWay binding. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a container with the name `PART_ContentHost`.

Here's the complete example on how to create a control template for a textbox: [TextBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). In this case the textbox is presented inside a `ScrollViewer`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand your problem, you want to Show Text Value of Textbox in custom Textbox Control.
So for doing  this,  you must use [`Template-Binding`](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Template_Binding)in template Like :

```
<CustomControl Text="{TemplateBinding Text}">
```

***CustomControl*** refer to any control you use in Template.

Comment: Actually all I want to do is something quite opposite, pass value from ControlTemplate back to the TextBox.

Comment: I found solution for my problem. To access controls in ControlTemplate we can call "FindName" method on template associated with control.